# while submitting code for leetcode array rotation question i came up with a solution which solves the problem in O(1)

Tags: python, list, data-structures

but the platform isnt accepting the solution
Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.

Example 1:

```
Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3
Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
Explanation:
rotate 1 steps to the right: [7,1,2,3,4,5,6]
rotate 2 steps to the right: [6,7,1,2,3,4,5]
rotate 3 steps to the right: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
Example 2:

Input: nums = [-1,-100,3,99], k = 2
Output: [3,99,-1,-100]
Explanation: 
rotate 1 steps to the right: [99,-1,-100,3]
rotate 2 steps to the right: [3,99,-1,-100]
```

Code i had submitted is:

```
class Solution:
def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
    
    """
    Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
    """
    nums = nums[-k:]+nums[:-k]
    print(nums)
```

Output is:

```
Your input 
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
3

Your stdout
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Your answer
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
Expected answer
[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
```

so while debugging with print statement it can be seen that the nums has been updated but the console is returning the un-updated version of nums.

Comment: You're not modifying the list in place. You're creating a new list and assigning it to the local variable. That has no effect on the original list.

Comment: It's also not O(1). List slicing is O(n). List addition is also O(n)

Comment: Try this way: ```nums[:] = nums[-k:] +nums[:-k]```   Prob. need this too: ```z = len(nums);  k = k % z``` before prev. statement